# Functor and type classes

Tags: haskell, functor

I'm a new of Haskell. I've understand what is functor and category.

But I have another question. Must I use a functor with `Functor` type class?

I think I can also define another type class to do the same as `Functor`?

Both of them can do the same.

```
instance Functor MyData where
    fmap f (MyData a) = MyData (f a)
```

And

```
class MyDataFunctor f where
   fmap :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b

instance MyDataFunctor MyData where
   fmap f (MyData a) = MyData (f a)
```

Comment: You certainly can, but this defeats the purpose of having a single interface (which is what typeclasses enable), don't you think?

Comment: Of course, using the built-in Functor is not mandatory. But you will lose many benefits of the standard Functor if you don't use it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sure you can do this. It's just kinda reinventing the wheel. The advantage of standard classes is that everybody will make their types instances of them if appropriate, so if you write a function that can operate on a generic `Functor f` then it'll work with a *huge* number of different type constructors `f` from hundreds of libraries. If you change the function to require `MyDataFunctor f` instead, it'll do exactly the same thing, but *only* with your own type `MyData`.

The only sensible reason you might want to write your own class is if you want *different* behaviour.